# Copying a pointer-containing struct in C - how does it work?

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

I got an assignment to tell what the prints are going to be and I didn't understand something.
Why in the line of `//***OUTPUT #1***` it prints

```
first array is:  
0 1 2 30
```

and not

```
first array is:  
0 1 2 3
```

If they write `T2 = T1` so that means they point to the same address and all changes made to `T2` will be the same as doing changes to `T1`?

I thought that it's not like that, because those are 2 variables and `T2` will copy the data in T1 but in a new address.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct myArray
{
    int *iArr;
    int size;
    char name[10];
}MyArray;

void printArray(MyArray T);

int main()
{
    MyArray T1,T2;
    int i;
    T1.size = 4;
    T1.iArr = (int *) calloc(T1.size, sizeof(int));
    strcpy(T1.name, "first");
    for (i=0; i<T1.size;i++)
    {
        T1.iArr[i] = i;
    }
    printArray(T1);
    T2 = T1;
    T2.iArr[3] = T1.iArr[3]*10;
    T2.size=2;
    printArray(T1); //***OUTPUT #1***
    printArray(T2);
    strcpy(T2.name, "second");
    T2.iArr = (int *) calloc(T2.size, sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<T2.size;i++)
    {
        T2.iArr[i] = -i;
    }
    printArray(T1);
    printArray(T2);
    return 0;
}

void printArray(MyArray T)
{
    int i;
    printf("%s array is:\n",T.name);
    for(i=0;i<T.size;i++)
    {
        printf ("%d ",T.iArr[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: The question statement is unreadable. Please add some capitalization, punctuation and formatting to it.

Comment: `T2.iArr == T1.iArr`, so although T1 and T2 are different variables, they each contain a pointer to the same memory location.

Comment: so if i change T2.name to "test", T1.name should be affected also?

Comment: At the time you make the assignment to `T2.iArr[3]`, that is the same as `T1.iArr[3]`.  You later change `T2.iArr` to point to a different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you copy all the values from the members of T1 to T2, a so called "shallow" copying.

```
T2 = T1;
```

This includes the address inside the pointer, shallow. I.e. both refer to the same memory area.
Into that single memory, referenced from both, you write here a value 10 times as much as already is in there.

```
T2.iArr[3] = T1.iArr[3]*10;
```

Before and after that, both pointers point to the same and via both pointers you would hence read the "30".
Which you do here.

```
printArray(T1); //***OUTPUT #1***
printArray(T2);
```

For a "deep" copy which does not exhibit the observed behavior, you'd have to create a new copy of the pointed-to memory (i.e. do another `calloc()`).

So:

> if they write T2 = T1 so that means they point to the same address and all changes made to T2 will be the same as doing changes to T1?

Yes, exactly.

But

> I thought that it's not like that because those are 2 variables so T2 will copy the data in T1 but in a new address

Yes (shallow) and no (not deep).
Yes, all the values from T1 are copied to new memory within T2, but the pointer in both contain the same value/address.
So no, what they are pointing to is the same memory, the one which you initially got from the first `calloc()`.

Yes, the two pointers (residing in different memory) point to the same memory. No, not to different dynamically allocated memory parts.

This does not change until you do

```
T2.iArr = (int *) calloc(T2.size, sizeof(int));
```

You get close to completing the deep copy here, though with different values

```
for(i=0;i<T2.size;i++)
{
    T2.iArr[i] = -i; // different values
  //T2.iArr[i] = T1.iArr[i]; // deep copy variant, keeping the "30"

}
```